Chevron/Arrow Navbar in HTML CSS
So I am trying to create a simple long chevron or arrow bar, which when selected shows a border staying within the height of all unselected chevrons/arrows. I have the example below but it clips the yellow border from top and the border at bottom of chevron is completely invisible, if any CSS wizard can help with this, I would really appreciate.


html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 1em;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 1em;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

ul.chevrons {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 2.5em;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  background-color: #e3edf9;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.chevrons li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  float: left;
}

ul.chevrons li {
  width: 25%;
  /* This changes based on how many items are in the flow. 3 items = 33% and 2 items = 50% */
}

ul.chevrons li a {
  width: 100%;
  color: #212121;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 0.75em;
}

ul.chevrons li a.selected {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: #013e75;
  color: #fff;
}

ul.chevrons li a.previous {
  color: #6c6c6c;
}

ul.chevrons li a:before,
ul.chevrons li a:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  left: 100%;
}

ul.chevrons li a:before {
  border-left: 0.75em solid yellow;
  margin-left: -0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul.chevrons li a:after {
  border-left: 0.75em solid #e3edf9;
  margin-left: -2px;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul.chevrons li a.selected:after {
  border-left: 0.75em solid #013e75;
}

ul.chevrons li:last-child a:before,
ul.chevrons li:last-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul class="chevrons">
    <li><a href="#" class="previous">Step 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="selected">Step 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Step 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Step 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>



Tried a few examples, but this is the best one I could get.

To make the selected a tag has full border, I updated ul.chevrons li a.selected class. In this class, I added height to make the selected a has same height with other a tags. Then I added new classes top-border and bottom-botter and removed the gap created by :after and :before.
ul.chevrons li a.selected {
  border: 1.5px solid yellow;
  background-color: #013e75;
  color: #fff;
  height: calc(2.5em - 3px);
}




const selectedLink = document.querySelector('.chevrons li a.selected');

const topBorder = document.createElement('span');
topBorder.classList.add('top-border');

const bottomBorder = document.createElement('span');
bottomBorder.classList.add('bottom-border');

selectedLink.appendChild(topBorder);
selectedLink.appendChild(bottomBorder);
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 1em;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 1em;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

ul.chevrons {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 2.5em;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  background-color: #e3edf9;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.chevrons li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  float: left;
}

ul.chevrons li {
  width: 25%;
  /* This changes based on how many items are in the flow. 3 items = 33% and 2 items = 50% */
}

ul.chevrons li a {
  width: 100%;
  color: #212121;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 0.75em;
}

ul.chevrons li a.selected {
  border: 1.5px solid yellow;
  background-color: #013e75;
  color: #fff;
  height: calc(2.5em - 3px);
}

ul.chevrons li a.previous {
  color: #6c6c6c;
}

ul.chevrons li a:before,
ul.chevrons li a:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  left: 100%;
}

ul.chevrons li a:before {
  border-left: 0.75em solid yellow;
  margin-left: -0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul.chevrons li a:after {
  border-left: 0.75em solid #e3edf9;
  margin-left: -2px;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul.chevrons li a.selected:after {
  border-left: 0.75em solid #013e75;
}

ul.chevrons li:last-child a:before,
ul.chevrons li:last-child a:after {
  display: none;
}

.top-border {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 1.5px;
  background: yellow;
  right: -2px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.bottom-border {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1.5px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 1.5px;
  background: yellow;
  right: -2px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul class="chevrons">
    <li><a href="#" class="previous">Step 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="selected">Step 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Step 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Step 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




This just takes the border off from top, while I wanted border on all sides when selected.

Hi, @Fahadhastocode. I understood what you want correctly and updated my answer. Please check it now and let me knnow if you have any other problems.

This is very helpful and solves the problem that I had initially, just a small problem with it is that it shows the blue overlay(don't know the exact word for it), when you zoom in or out.

I have tried to do the same with different approach.  And this is a bit easier to maintain and edit.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 1em;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 1em;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

ul.chevrons {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 2.5em;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  background-color: #e3edf9;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.chevrons li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  float: left;
  
  width: 25%;
  /* This changes based on how many items are in the flow. 3 items = 33% and 2 items = 50% */
  
  color: #FFF;
}

ul.chevrons li a,
ul.chevrons li a.selected {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.chevrons li a.selected {
  color: #FFF;
}

ul.chevrons li a:before,
ul.chevrons li a:after,
ul.chevrons li a.selected:before,
ul.chevrons li a.selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 21px;
  width: 96%;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
    transform: skew(30deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

ul.chevrons li a:after,
ul.chevrons li a.selected:after {
  top: 21px;
  border-top: 0;
    transform: skew(-30deg);
}


ul.chevrons li a.selected:after,
ul.chevrons li a.selected:before {
  border: 2px solid #F00;
  background: #333;
}

ul.chevrons li a.selected:before {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

ul.chevrons li a.selected:after {
  border-top: 0;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul class="chevrons">
    <li><a href="#" class="previous">Step 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="selected">Step 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Step 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Step 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




The bottom border is present on your a.selected item, but the a.selected item has a greater height than your ul.chevrons (which has overflow: hidden). As a result, the border is not visible.
Adjusting the height didn’t prove effective, so instead, I removed the border attribute from a.selected and replaced it with a box-shadow. Here’s how you can style your a.selected to achieve the desired look:
box-shadow: inset 0 2px 0 yellow, inset 0 -2px 0 yellow;


this does get the job done for the bottom border, however I wanted a complete border without clipping, while this still leaves the issue where border isn't complete upto the end i.e.  arrowhead.
